# handling hashbang url with ng-route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

i m using location.path to navigate like

```
$location.path('#/foo');
```

while in app I am using route provider like

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/foo",{
        templateUrl: "templates/foo.html",
        controller: "fooController"
    })
    .otherwise({
    template : "<h1>None</h1><p>Nothing has been selected</p>"
    });
   });
```

but instead of producing url like

```
http://localhost:8001/#/foo
```

location.path traverses to

```
http://localhost:8001/#/%23/foo
```

and hence routeprovider is loading otherwise template and not the required template doesn't loads. How can I check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove explicit `#` from your route in `$location.path('#/foo');`
and change it to `$location.path('/foo');`

because angular itself append `# tag` during route, which already seen in your question `http://localhost:8001/#/%23/foo`, and when you give explicit one, then it encodes to `%23`

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the # you put in $location.path(). It's already added by default.

```
$location.path('/foo');
```